# Powershell TrimEnd trims trailing e's

Tags: powershell

I've been tasked with converting XML files exported from PDFs into XML files usable by another program. I'm using Powershell for this. I have noticed that when I trim the end of lines, if there is a trailing *e*, the *e* is also removed. And it's not just one *e*. If there are multiple *e*'s, they are all trimmed. For example:

```
$lines[i].TrimStart(">").TrimEnd("</field")
```

If the line given is:

```
>123 Sycamore</field
```

The result is:

```
123 Sycamor
```

If the line given is:

```
>Agee</field
```

The result is:

```
Ag
```

Interestingly, this only happens to lowercase *e*'s. So, if the line is:

```
>LANE</field
```

The result is:

```
LANE
```

I wasn't able to locate anything on technet or in the documentation. (Maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing.)

Anyone have any ideas on this? Am I implementing the function incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`TrimEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx) takes a `char[]` as parameter, not a string. PowerShell will implicitly convert the string to its underlying characters array, which will then mean: Remove the following characters from the end of the string: `<`, `/`, `f`, `i`, `e`, `l`, `d`. The documentation also points this out quite clearly, so if you didn't arrive at [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx), then yes, I guess you were searching for the wrong thing :-)

If you meant to remove the *string* `</field>` from the end of another string, you can use a regular expression:

```
$s -replace '</field>$'
```

You can even combine that with your `TrimStart` in this case:

```
$lines[$i] -replace '^>|</field>$'
```

Comment: No, I was searching for the issue itself. I only saw trailing *e*'s being removed, so I was searching for that. I suppose I would have paid more attention to the `char[]` if I had seen other letters removed.

Comment: Granted, it helps knowing the BCL a bit.